# add_filter with specific thumb names

Tags: filters, post-thumbnails, images

How would I run `add_filter` only on some specific registered thumbnail sizes '$size' ? like 'large' , 'medium', etc?

Answer (score 0):

The `class` attribute contains the size in the format `attachment-$size`, you could do a check for a specific size like:

```
if( strstr( $attr['class'], 'thumb' ) ):
    // size is attachment-thumb
endif;
```

Comment: thanks for response, but nothing happen! i think the filter is server side and this check is client